How to match GraphHopper's roads against TomTom's roads?
Currently using TomTom’s real-time traffic data in the form of Vector Flow Tile to update the values of GraphHopper’s graph’s edges. TomTom’s lists of coordinates, or the geometries, representing roads are put through the map-matching algorithm to increase the accuracy of the coordinates, then each of the geometries’ corresponding GraphHopper’s roads are located using LocationIndex. All in all, the process of locating edges is not an issue.
The difficulty we’re having is the inaccuracy of the speed value (the updated speed value from the real-time traffic data) resulting from the difference between what TomTom defines as a unit of road and what GraphHopper defines as a unit of road. For example,

Let’s say TomTom regards road A to span 20km, but GraphHopper divides this road into two different roads A and B, spanning 10km and 10km, respectively. Then, the real-time traffic data is too generalized and doesn’t reflect the granularity of the localized traffic.
Inversely, TomTom regards road A to span 10km, but GraphHopper regards this as a part of a larger road B spanning 20km. Then, there the real-time traffic data won’t cover the rest of the road, since once updated edge will be excluded from any further updates to prevent duplicate updates.

Is there an efficient way to overcome this issue?
